# Open text document in custom editor from vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I'm developing a Visual Studio Code extension that opens a webview custom editor.

Part of this is a command that prompts the user for a filename, creates the file, and then opens it.

It looks something like this:

```ts
window
  .showInputBox({
    prompt: "Enter name for file",
  })
  .then((title) => {
    if (!title) {
      return;
    }

    const fileContent = generateDefaultFileContent();
    const filePath = path.join(folder.uri.path, `${title}.custom_file_format`);

    workspace.fs
      .writeFile(
        folder.uri.with({
          path: filePath,
        }),
        Buffer.from(fileContent, "utf8")
      )
      .then(() => {
        workspace.openTextDocument(filePath).then((doc) =>
          window.showTextDocument(doc, {
            viewColumn: ViewColumn.Active,
          })
        );
      });
  });
```

The file gets properly created, however the call to `window.showTextDocument` opens the editor in the text editor and not my registered custom editor (in the example above, the custom editor will open `.custom_file_format` files). If you click on the newly created file in the file explorer, it will open in the custom editor.

Is there a way to get it to open the new file in the custom editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this can be done with...

```ts
commands.executeCommand(
  "vscode.openWith",
  folder.uri.with({
    path: filePath,
  }),
  MyCustomEditor.viewType
);
```